# AppWidgetProvider handle touch event problem

Tags: android, android-widget

i am adding installed AppWidgetViews to my application as AppWidgetHostView. The problem is they don't handle any touch events as they were added to home screen. Here is part of my code;

---

```
AppWidgetHost host = new AppWidgetHost(getContext(), HOST_ID);
AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getContext());

int id = host.allocateAppWidgetId();
AppWidgetHostView view = host.createView(getContext(), id, info);
```

---

Lets say AppWidgetProviderInfo object "info" belongs to "com.android.alarmclock.AnalogAppWidgetProvider", which is the default analog clock widget of android. This view has to launch clock setting when a click performed on it as it performed on home screen, still i have no response from it. Is there a way to solve this problem? Thanks in advance...

Comment: I have similar problem ( appwidgethostview doesn't accept long click event ) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074372/appwidgethostview-cant-handle-onclick-onlongclick-properly

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will answer your question.

To handle onClick event in android homescreen, I use PendingIntent to setOnClick behavior.

```
Intent iText = new Intent(this, urTargetActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingText = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, iText,0);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.textView1,pendingText);
```

I am not sure about using it with AppWidgetHostView but the way I have done before is using it in the service to call the configuration activity page which is working without any problem.

Hope this could help you somehow :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Fon, still i won't be able to check if it works or not since i will be away from my workspace for a week. I will take a look and try your suggestion about PendingIntents once i return, still one thing makes me curious. Here in my example, i used appWidget developed by Google, which probably won't let me to access to the id of widget element like you decleared "R.id.textView1". Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Fon i tested, your answer. Even though you are right that widgets should implement PendingIntent stuff, which works on default Android home screen launcher, for event handling, still my launcher implementation fails to execute them... Maybe it's about permissions or similar things i have to add on AndroidManifest.xml, i'm gonna dig that... After all, your answer is invalid for my question. StackOverflow help me! :)

Comment: So, can we use pendingIntent in AppWidgetHostView? What is the fails that you got in LogCat? I am curious about it also. Would you mind to share it? Thanks...