# Cannot cast from AppWidgetHostView to MyAppWidgetHostView

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I need to catch longClick-Events from AppWidgetHostViews like discussed here:

[appwidgethostview-cant-handle-onclick-onlongclick-properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074372/appwidgethostview-cant-handle-onclick-onlongclick-properly/25184730#25184730)

So i need write a class that extends AppWidgetHostView for this, but when it comes to:

```
MyAppWidgetHostView hostView = (MyAppWidgetHostView) m_AppWidgetHost.createView(this, appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo);
```

....App crashes. Cannot typecast from AppWidgetHostView to MyAppWidgetHostView. What am i doing wrong/misssing?

Comment: Google downcasting and why this case is not available in Java.

Comment: ok i understand it, but how can i do this (catching the long-click on AppWidgets) then? It worked at least for one person in the linked post....

Comment: You can't, it is a conceptual error. You need to rethink your architecture and maybe make AppWidgetHostView a field/child of your new view instead. Look at his code closely, he never casts.

Comment: thx a lot MLProgrammer-CiM , it works now and really learned from this.