# Receiving Android's widget longpress feedback on App Widget Host

Tags: android, widget, android-appwidget

I'am building an Android "Launcher" like app, with a App Widget Host. Inside my view I can freely drag and drop the widget if it is a simple view, but if it is a more complex view with buttons and such like the google drive widget, or the clock for example, I'm not able to receive the long press feedback on the view, because the press is mostly on a button inside the widget.

Is there a way to receive a long press from the widget, or any workaround that I can try to overcome this trouble?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Others have found a way here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074372/appwidgethostview-cant-handle-onclick-onlongclick-properly